# How rich text editor works? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im new in react-native and im building a notebloc to get started, the problem is that to do this:

[image]

write, put an image and then continue to write below of it, i need a richt text editor component, the problem is that there very few out there, and they are outdate to react-version 0.60, so in nutshell i have to build my own, but the only problem that i dont know and dont understand, its the image, how i concatenate string with images? i mean, writing, insert the image and then make a line break and continue to write below, thats a kind of format? please thanks :)

Comment: That's very broad. To start, are you familiar with HTML? It should translate fairly straightforwardly to JSX.

Comment: Have you written any JSX so far, with which you're having a particular issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask